# Debugging a makefile step by step

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wxwidgets, makefile

I want to debug a makefile . I came across many posts in Stackoverflow but still need some help .

```
INCLUDEPATHS=/I"/C:/wxWidgetsDev/lib/vc_lib/mswd" /I"/C:/wxWidgetsDev/include/msvc/"
LIBPATHS=LIBPATH:"/C:/wxWidgetsDev/lib/vc_lib"
HEADERS=headers.h util.h main.h serialize.h uint256.h db.h base58.h
```

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

The INCLUDEPATHS and LIBPATHS refer to the include and lib files respectively

I am giving the following command in the commandprompt

```
nmake -f makefile.vc

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file 'wx/wx.h.
```

The wx/wx.h file is present in the INCLUDEPATH C:/wxWidgetsDev/include/msvc/ , but its still flagging the error .

Comment: Hi @Sujay, did you find out how do debug the make file?

Comment: Hi @Nation , I dont remember now; whether the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first step: Is `%INCLUDEPATHS%` being used in the makefile compiler line? Otherwise, you're just setting an environment variable that's being used exactly *nowhere* :-)

I don't know if this is supposed to be automatically added by the compiler or whether you have to do it manually.

Also you refer to both `INCLUDEPATHS` and `INCLUDEPATH` in your question - which should it be, if automatic. If manual, you can make it anything just so long as you add it to the compile line.

Comment: I think it is a path problem. The problem gets solved if I put the boost from C:\Program Files\boost to c:\boost 

I think there is something wrong in the path settings, I have given in the makefile . Can you see something wrong in the path

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment on the first answer, could it be that it doesn't handle spaces in the pathname?